# Nullity of the linear transformation when the field is $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $f : \mathbb{F}^3 \to \mathbb{F}^3$ denote the map dened by $$f(x; y; z) = (x + y,\ x + z,\ y + z).$$
>   Determine the rank and the nullity of $f$ when $\mathbb{F}$ = $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
>   \begin{align*}
> Ker\ f & =\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{F}\ :\ f(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)  \}\\
>        & =\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{F}\ :\ (x + y,\ x + z,\ y + z) =(0,0,0)  \}
> \end{align*}
>   So we got that $x+y,\ y+z,\ x+z$ all are divisible by $2$ so all have the same parity. Now how will be the nullity will be determined?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you think of any vectors at all that are in the kernel of $f$, aside from the obvious $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, it $(1,1,1)$

Comment: Good. Now comes the big question: are there any others? (It's not that tough of a question, really; there are only $6$ elements left of $\Bbb F^3$ to check.)

Comment: No, since the parity of all are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix of $f$ with respect to the standard basis for $\mathbb{F}^3$ is:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}_.$$

Row reducing when $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}_2$ yields:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}_.$$

Therefore $\text{rank}(A) = 2$ and $\text{nullity}(A) = 1$ (by the Rank-Nullity Theorem).

---

Explicitly, the reduced row echelon form tells us that if $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \ker(f)$, then $x_1 = -x_3 = x_3$ and $x_2 = -x_3 = x_3$. So $\ker(f) = \text{span}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: Of course this matrix was particularly nice and you could have read the information about the kernel straight from $A$. However, in most problems computing the row echelon form is helpful.